# Why does a class with a user-declared destructor have an implicitly defaulted constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

Code:

```
struct A
{ 
    ~A(){ };
};

A::A(){ }; //error: definition of implicitly declared default constructor

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19b0756ca4ae8f54)**

Why does the code produces the error? I expected that the program compiles fine. The Standard says `N3797::12.8/7 [class.copy]`:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the
>   implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise,
>   it is defined as defaulted (8.4). *The latter case is deprecated if the*
>   *class has* a user-declared copy assignment operator or a *user-declared*
>   *destructor*.

It's a bug or my misunderstanding?

Comment: You can only provide definitions for functions that you declared yourself...  there's no such thing as giving a non-inline body for an implicitly-declared function

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yeah, I've understood it from answer. But what's the point to mark such functions as default. They've declared by a compiler already.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: There is no need (assuming you are not doing anything which causes the function to be deleted). Some people do it because they want to be very explicit about what functions are available in their classes. A lot of people don't approve of implicitly declared functions, and would prefer if every function was required to be explicit.

Comment: That's quite a different question to what you just posted.  (a) marking it as default means the function exists when it might not have (e.g. move-constructor for class with user-declared destructor);  (b) self-documentation

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, I know what `default` keyword actually does. _If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted_. That _otherwise, it is defined as defaulted_  suggests that a compiler may declare implicitly defined function as _defaulted_ and as _not defaulted_.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm interested in what's the point of implicitly decalred not defaulted constructor?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: you're misunderstanding... it can be *deleted* or *defaulted* or user-defined.  The text you quote just uses "defined as defaulted* as a short-hand for the implicitly defined copy constructor behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not define an implicitly declared constructor by the compiler.

From the C++ Standard (12 Special member functions)

> 1. ... Programs **shall not** define implicitly-declared special member functions

Comment: It's not quote obvious to me. Defaulted constructor means it's defined at the point of declaration by implementation. Since the case is deprecated the constructor doesn't have to be marked as default, therefore I may provide it definition by my own.

Comment: Ah, regarding for your latest edit... So what's the point to mark implicitly defined member function as _defaulted_?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv All class members shall be defined within the class definition except the implicitly declared by the compiler special member functions. If you did not declared a member then you may not define it as a member outside the class.

Comment: That's I shoudn't be concerned if implicitly member function declared as defaulted, should I?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv For example when you declared a constructor with parameters when the default constructor will not be declared implicitly by the compiler.

Answer (score 6):

```
struct A
{ 
  ~A(){ };
   A();
};

A::A(){ }; //here you can define default constructor

int main()
{
 A a;
}
```

you have defined explicit destructor not constructor , add constructor declarartion and define it as  outside clas